# How to convert tsr xml to xpath selenium

Tags: xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, qtp

I want to migrate my scripts  from QTP to selenium .For that I need to get the xml file from tsr file.From these xml I need to extract the xpath and use it in selenium.If any one of you have migrated please assist me.In short qtp scripts to selenium in generic way.

Comment: I don´t think there is a generic way to convert. There simply are too many features in QTP that cannot be easily mapped 1:1 to selenium.

Comment: Atleast i want to have the mapped properties from qtp xml to Selenium elements properties.Any one please help me any xml experts.